# Access value of textarea in jQuery with multiple same Id's?

Tags: jquery, function, html, jquery-mobile, textarea

I have multiple div tag's of "**post**" name in my page, what I want to do is post data on server on the submit click. I cannot retrieve value of textarea "**commentText**" in my jquery method **commentPost()**.

```
<div id="post">
  <br>topic containtment is here
  <form name="postComment" id="commentForm" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post"    
   target="_top" onsubmit="return commentPost();">
    <textarea name="comment" id="commentText" cols="10" rows="3" accesskey="1">
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="commentpost" value="Submit" accesskey="2">
   </form>
</div>
```

jQuery Method

```
function commentPost()
{
    alert("Inside commentpost");
        //how to get value of commentText
    var comment=("form > commentText").val(); //<--not working
    alert(comment);
    //further code to be written
}
```

NOTICE: there are multiple **div post** tag in the page.

how to get value of textarea.??

Comment: "there are multiple div post tag in the page"... then you have invalid markup. Change it to a class name instead. ID values must be unique.

Comment: commentPost method has syntax mistakes. It should be `var comment = $('form > #commentText').val()` You are missing the dollarsign function and the hashtag nominating a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single id in your document with the value of "commentText" then your function should look like this:

```
function commentPost()
{
    alert("Inside commentpost");
        //how to get value of commentText
    var comment=("form > #commentText").val(); //<--not working
    alert(comment);
    //further code to be written
}
```

If you have more tags with this id, your markup is invalid and you should change id="commentText" to class ="commentText" in your markup. Your function should look like this in this case:

```
function commentPost()
{
    alert("Inside commentpost");
        //how to get value of commentText
    var comment=("form > .commentText").val(); //<--not working
    alert(comment);
    //further code to be written
}
```

When this works don't forget to remove the alerts from your function.

Answer (score 1):

It's [not valid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) to have multiple elements with the same `ID`.

If you solve that problem, then your jQuery issue will be solved indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

`id` must be able to identify a *unique* element on the page.

Typically, what you're trying to do can be solved by using a `class`:

```
<textarea name="comment" class="commentText" cols="10" rows="3" accesskey="1">
</textarea><br>
```

Then, use `$("form > .commentText")`.